# Can't get my javascript action to run on tablet & mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, tablet

I have put together a website and using javascript to run a script that allows you to move between one image and another to see the before and after of an image. The javascript works fine on a desktop but on a mobile and tablet I can't get the same effect to run properly. Do I need to include something to enable to this work on mobile & tablet?

This is one of the pages that I am on about where the effect is active. [Here](http://www.ryankerswell.co.uk/design/visible-me.html)

You will need to view this on a mobile and tablet to see it not working as it should.

Also here is the javascript that I am using if it helps. Let me know if you  require anything else.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrapper = $("div.reveal-visible");

    wrapper.mousedown(function(e) {
        $(this).data("sliding", true);
        var offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left
        $(this).find('div').width(offs);
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        if ($(this).data("sliding")) {
            var offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left
            $(this).find('div').width(offs);
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        wrapper.data("sliding", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use "touchstart" and "touchend" with the Jquery bind method instead of mouseup and mousedown.

Comment: Or better yet, use them both ~$(wrapper).bind ("mousedown touchstart", function (){});~

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sorry to be a pain but how would I put this into my javascript as not sure what to edit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11145262/1478764) to a similar question. The premise is to use JQuery's [bind method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) which attaches a handler to an event for an element it is applied to. The bind method takes an *eventType* argument, which is a String containing *one or more* DOM events. The method also takes a function, which it should execute when the event has occurred, as an argument.

Then for mobile devices (which have touchscreens) use the touch equivalents of the mouse events: **touchstart, touchmove, touchend**.

So, change your code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrapper = $("div.reveal-visible");

    wrapper.bind("mousedown touchstart", function(e){
        $(this).data("sliding", true);
        var offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left
        $(this).find('div').width(offs);
    });

    wrapper.bind("mousemove touchmove", function(e){
        if ($(this).data("sliding")) {
            var offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left
            $(this).find('div').width(offs);
        }
    });

    $(document).bind("mouseup touchend", function(e){
        wrapper.data("sliding", false);
    });

});
```

**Edit:** Okay, so the reason it didn't work this time is because when it's a touch screen we have to get the touch point from the [touch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events). Instead of using `e.pageX` for the touchscreen, use `e.changedTouches[0].pageX`. So here's the updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var wrapper = $("div.reveal-visible");

    wrapper.bind("mousedown touchstart", function(e){
        var offs;
        $(this).data("sliding", true);
        if(typeof e.changedTouches === "undefined" || e.changedTouches == null){
            offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        }else{
            offs = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        }
        $(this).find("div").width(offs);
    });

    wrapper.bind("mousemove touchmove", function(e){
        if($(this).data("sliding")){
            var offs;
            if(typeof e.changedTouches === "undefined" || e.changedTouches == null){
                offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            }else{
                offs = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            }
            $(this).find("div").width(offs);
        }
    });

    $(document).bind("mouseup touchend", function(e){
        wrapper.data("sliding", false);
    });

});
```

**Edit:** So, the code was correct but the problem was with the JQuery [Event Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/). The JQuery event object only supports certain types of events and the touch events are not included. There is [JQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/), which including a link to that library should fix your problem. But I chose to intermingle more "plain" JavaScript into the code to not have to rely on another resource. The below code is tested and works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var wrapper = $("div.reveal-visible");
        var w = document.getElementsByClassName("reveal-visible")[0];

        w.addEventListener("touchstart", start);
        w.addEventListener("touchmove", move);
        wrapper.bind("mousedown", start);
        wrapper.bind("mousemove", move);

        function start(e){
            var offs;
            $(this).data("sliding", true);
            if(typeof e.changedTouches === "undefined" || e.changedTouches == null){
                offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            }else{
                offs = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            }
            $(this).find("div").width(offs);
        }

        function move(e){
             if($(this).data("sliding")){
                 var offs;
                 if(typeof e.changedTouches === "undefined" || e.changedTouches == null){
                     offs = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
                 }else{
                     offs = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - $(this).offset().left;
                 }
                 $(this).find("div").width(offs);
             }
        }

        $(document).bind("mouseup touchend", function(e){
            wrapper.data("sliding", false);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Ok I added this to my code but it still doesn't work on mobile or tablet. You can see here with the above code added to the website. http://www.ryankerswell.co.uk/design/visible-me.html

Comment: Ok tried that code and still not working. This new code is now on the webpage for you to see.

Comment: Here is a Jsfiddle of the code in action if it helps :) http://jsfiddle.net/bfccbxg8/

Comment: Also again if it helps this is where I got the inspiration from and this one works on mobile and tablet exactly as I want it to. :) http://www.theguardian.com/uk/interactive/2011/aug/09/london-riots-before-after-photographs

Comment: Hi this works on mobile and tablet now but im getting a javascript error on the 2 pages where this javascript is placed. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" on this piece of code `w.addEventListener("touchmove", move);` Also because of this my hamburger menu has stopped working because of this error. Got any ideas :)

Comment: I have no errors in the JavaScript code using the HTML and CSS you provided in the jsfiddle. Therefore the error is caused by something else unless you altered the code. Make sure that you are placing the code in `$(document).ready();` as I have done in the code provided. Try putting an id on the div and use `document.getElementById("id")` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("reveal-visible")[0]`. If you do use getElementsByClassName, make sure to put the index at the end, ex: `[0]`. Use logging to locate your exact problem: `console.log("place these strategically")`.

Comment: Ok found the problem. The code you supplied was correct but if I duplicate it inside the same JS file this is where the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" comes up. By separating the code to a separate JS file it solves the problem. Thank you ;)

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.