# Holdable button on JS. How need rewrite code for correctly work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Holdable button works on desktop, but doesn't work on mobile

```
clicker.mousedown(function(){
    timeout = setInterval(function(){
        clicker.text(count++);
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/
what's wrong?

Comment: This post could probably help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144370/using-mousedown-event-on-mobile-without-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it by actual hold, you'd do something like:

```
var timeoutContainer;

// this should work with mouse only

$el.on('mousedown', function(ev) {
    if(ev.type=='click'){
        timeoutContainer = setInterval(function(){
        // your stuff.
        }, timeToHold);
    }
}); 

$el.on('mouseup', function(ev) {
    clearInterval(timeoutContainer);
}); 

// or, if you only want to apply it to touch. 

$el.on('touchstart', function(ev) {
    timeoutContainer = setTimeout(function(){
    // your stuff.
    }, timeToHold);
}); 

$el.on('touchend', function(ev) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutContainer);
});
```

After looking at your fiddle, it may not be working as expected because of touchcancel. I noticed you have document.mouseup. It might be treating moving finger as a mouse up or something. If you do it explicitly as touch start it may behave differently. You'd need to check for mobile before as above in the mouse down part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use touchstart and touchend events to detect a touch on a button on mobile devices. On some devices touchmove might also trigger so you can also check for that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events