# jQuery + Android. Apply function(Touchstart, touchmove) to live loaded content

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am working on mobile site, and I wanted to do mouseover highlighting on my links which have class name "list_anchor" by using jQuery instead of using HTML's :hover pseudo selector.
('cause :hover is bit buggy in Android.)

So I followed this tutorial:
[Stop the touchstart performing too quick when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842587/stop-the-touchstart-performing-too-quick-when-scrolling)

and I successfully installed touchstart,touchmove function to my links.
Happy for a while.

However, I have links which is lively loaded when users scroll(swipe) to the bottom of the page(like Twitter).
The Javascript does not seem to be applied for those links.

Here's what I got so far:

```
function touchEvent() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass('hover');
    //behaviour for move
    self.on('touchmove', function(e){
        self.removeClass('hover');
    });     
}
$('a,section').filter('.list_anchor').on('touchstart', this, touchEvent);
```

Any help, suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `on` to work like the old `live` you need to attach it to something high up the DOM, and put the selector in the parameters, e.g.:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.list_anchor', touchEvent);
```